# how to make <ol> not resetting to 1 even <ol> breaks

Tags: html-lists

Is there anyway to get this code

```
<ol>
  <li>num</li>
</ol>

<ul>  
  <li>num</li>
</ul>

<ol>
  <li>num</li>
</ol>
```

to display

```
1. num
   . num
2. num
```

I need the number to continue even the ol is not continuous.

Answer (score 1):

You mean this:

```html
<ol>
  <li>num</li>
  <ul>  
      <li>num</li>
  </ul>
  
  <li>num</li>
  <ul>  
     <li>num</li>
  </ul>
  
  <li>num</li>
  <ul>  
     <li>num</li>
  </ul>
  
  <li>num</li>
  <ul>  
     <li>num</li>
</ul>
</ol>
```

Comment: if i can't change the markup structure but i still want to display like that?

Comment: @Sean i do not think that is possible, unless if you will generate your markup using javascript

Comment: i saw someone having the same problem too
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615500/how-to-start-a-new-list-continuing-the-numbering-from-the-previous-list

but unlike his, i can't add classes to my markup...