# HTML ordered list formatting

Tags: html, css, format

is it possible to have my ordered list in the following format?

```
heading
1.1. text...
1.2. text
1.2.1 text

Another heading
1.3. text
1.3.1. text
1.3.2. text
1.4. text
```

Is that possible?
Thank you

Comment: This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615500/how-to-start-a-new-list-continuing-the-numbering-from-the-previous-list

Comment: This was already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098195/can-ordered-list-produce-result-that-looks-like-1-1-1-2-1-3-instead-of-just-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
ol { counter-reset: item }
li { display: block }
li:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item }
```

```html
<ol>
    <li> Cat</li>
    <li>Bat</li>
    <li>Mat
        <ol>
            <li>Red Mat</li>
            <li>Green Mat</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Pat</li>
    
</ol>
```

Comment: @user3054465: Let me know if this helped you.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.contract ol {
    counter-reset: item
}
.contract li.paragraph {
    counter-increment: item;
}
.contract li li.paragraph:before {
    content: counters(item, ".")" ";
}
.contract li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.contract ol {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="contract">
    <ol>
        <li class="paragraph">
            <ol>
                <li>
                     <h2>Heading</h2>

                </li>
                <li class="paragraph">text</li>
                <li class="paragraph">text
                    <ol>
                        <li class="paragraph">text</li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
                <li>
                     <h2>Another heading</h2>

                </li>
                <li class="paragraph">text
                    <ol>
                        <li class="paragraph">text</li>
                        <li class="paragraph">text</li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
                <li class="paragraph">text</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</section>
```