# Remove indent for element within an ordered list <ol>

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the left position of a table element which is within an ordered list.  What I would like to achieve is that the table span the entire width.  What seems to be happening is that, whatever I try, the table is always positioned with the same indent as the `<li>` element it is either within or adjacent to.

For example:

```
<ol>
        <li>
            <p>
                Something.
            </p>           
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>
                Something else, with an image this time.
                <figure.left>
                    <img src="SomeImage.png" style="max-width: 100%;width: 428px;height: auto;" />
                </figure.left>
            </p>
        </li>
        <table style="border-top-style:solid; border-top-width:1px; border-top-color:#d3d3d3; border-bottom-style:solid; border-bottom-width:1px; border-bottom-color:#d3d3d3; position:fixed; left:0px;" cellspacing="0">
             <col style="width: 48pt;" />
             <col style="width: 396pt;" />
             <tr>
                 <td>                         
                    <img src="TableImage.png" style="width:42px; height:auto;" />                           
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     <p>A paragraph in the table.</p>
                     <p>A second paragraph in the table.</p>
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
         <li>Last thing.</li>
    </ol>
```

So what I would like is the table to span the width of the page (I am outputting to a PDF, in fact).  I have tried:

```
style="position:fixed;left:0px;"
```

...which didn't work.

Any ideas on how to make the table element ignore the indent?

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you explain the syntax `<figure.left>` I don't recognise it.

Comment: OFF TOPIC:...but, I assumed this was simply the same as <figure class="left">, but it seems not.  Sorry, I should have removed this to make it clearer.  It think the software which I use to create PDFs from the HTML knows what this is and does something appropriate.

Comment: cheers for getting back to me, as I say I didn't recognise the syntax

Comment: BACK ON TOPIC: I've been experimenting with {position:absolute;} which seems to help with the x-position, but then mucks up the position within the list - see : http://jsfiddle.net/MrSpaceman/d6ya7LrL/9/

Comment: BUT, if I create a <div></div> which is the correct height, it holds the list items in the right places so that the table looks like it's in line: http://jsfiddle.net/MrSpaceman/d6ya7LrL/10/  Is there a way to make the <div> block take the height of its children?

Comment: Still looking for an answer to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come back to this with the answer I've settled on.

It seemed that changing the padding or the left position of the table element within the `<ol>` wasn't going to work, it just moved the table to the left and a gap appears at the right hand side.  The easiest way to get around this was to put the table element outside of the `<ol>` and restart the `<ol>` block.  By using a CSS counter, the numbering can be continued.

To achieve the counter continuation, I took some **inspiration** from this topic: [How to start a new list, continuing the numbering from the previous list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615500/how-to-start-a-new-list-continuing-the-numbering-from-the-previous-list)

However, I didn't like the need to apply a special class to the `<ol>` blocks; in my view, they've done nothing wrong here and it's the inclusion of the mid-way element that's special.  So, to indicate in the CSS that the numbering should be continued, I tried a CSS selector like:`ol + table + ol`. This targets the `<ol>` after the table which follows the initial `<ol>`. The continuing counter consideration is then made there by stipulating that counter-reset is none.

To avoid all `<ol>` continuing when these three elements are in a sequence, a class (`mid-ol`) can be added to the table and the CSS selector can be: `ol + table.mid-ol + ol` ...but, in fact, why stop there?  You could have ANY element with the `mid-ol` class in the midst of a couple of `<ol>` elements (e.g. a `div`, which might be useful!), so the selector becomes: ol + .mid-ol + ol.  I've checked that if you remove the class from the table that the second `<ol>` will start its counter reset.

The following link to a JSFiddle should illustrate **the solution**: 
https://jsfiddle.net/r7u4vgtz/

The only drawback of this answer is if you would like to start your first `<ol>` with a number that is not 1.  That's not the point of this question, so I've not gone that far.

Also, there was an issue with having `<p>` elements in the `<li>` elements after the counter related styling was added; the `<p>` elements were taking a new line, which they didn't do before. So I added that any `<p>` elements with an `<li>` parent were displayed inline, but then any subsequent `<p>` elements were displayed block, as usual.

For those who are browsing these answers and don't want to mess about with JSFiddle, here's a simple example HTML code for the answer:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style  type="text/css">

      table {
        width:100%; 
        border-top-style:solid; 
        border-top-width:1px; 
        border-top-color:#d3d3d3; 
        border-bottom-style:solid; 
        border-bottom-width:1px; 
        border-bottom-color:#d3d3d3;
      }

      ol { 
        counter-reset: mycounter; 
      }

      ol li { 
        counter-increment: mycounter;
        list-style-type: none;
      }

      ol li:before { 
        content: counter(mycounter) ". ";
        margin-left:-1.3em;
      }

      ol + .mid-ol + ol {
        counter-reset: none;
      }

      li > p {
        display: inline;
      }
      li > p + p {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ol>
      <li>
        <p>A list item with this paragraph element.</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Another list element using a paragraph element</p>
        <p>But with another paragraph within the same &lt;li&gt; to check that the paragraph styling is good. It seems that it is.  This second block uses display:block, as is proper for a paragraph.</p>
        <p>Here's a third paragraph in the same &lt;li&gt; element.  Now we can be sure the styling is good!</p>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <table cellspacing="0" class='mid-ol'>
       <col style="width: 48pt;" />
       <col style="width: 396pt;" />
       <tr>
         <td>
           <img src="http://woodworkingvdo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/small-tables-9.jpg" style="width:42px; height:auto;" />
         </td>
         <td>
           <p>This table is not indented, as it's actually outside of the &lt;ol&gt; block.</p>
           <p>It is defined as a .mid-ol class element, which allows special consideration for subsequent &lt;ol&gt; blocks.</p>
         </td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <ol>
       <li>
         <p>Last list item element.</p>
       </li>
     </ol>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ol { padding: 0 }
```

Should do the trick. Default `ol` styling has padding.

Comment: I don't think this exact approach would do exactly what I want.  Changing the overall style of the <ol> is not required, just the indent on the table part.

Comment: Ofcourse , add an appropriate class to your ol element and style that. I just wanted to point out where you indent is coming from.

Comment: OK, I understand.  I did try changing the padding because of your suggestion, but adding {padding: 0} to the <table> or an <li> containing a <table> doesn't seem to solve the issue.  
 
Have a look at this (also linked to in the comments under Bryan's suggested answer): https://jsfiddle.net/MrSpaceman/d6ya7LrL/  You can see what I'm trying to do, hopefully!

Comment: Also, it seems this is the crux of the issue: the <ol> has padding, which its children also have ("inherit"?), this include the <li> elements (which is great!) and the <table> element which I want to place in between some <li> elements (not so great!).  Is there a way of *breaking* the padding that is bestowed by the <ol>?  Can the table be floated, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/breezy/aL4aqgzu/

I was trying to understand what you are trying to achieve, it seems that you want a pdf inside the table, and there is some padding on the left of the table?

I saw that you didn't have the table inside an `li`, here is what I did.

```
     <li style="width:500px;
       height:600px;
       display:block;
       padding:0;
       margin:0;
       list-style: none;background: white;
       overflow:hidden;
       clear:both"> pdf goes here i think..just an example?

<table style="border-top-style:solid; border-op-width:1px; border-top-color:#d3d3d3; border-bottom-style:solid; border-bottom-width:1px; border-bottom-color:#d3d3d3; position:fixed; left:0px;" cellspacing="0">
            <col style="width: 48pt;" />
            <col style="width: 396pt;" />
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img src="TableImage.png" style="width:42px; height:auto;" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <p>A paragraph in the table.</p>
                <p>A second paragraph in the table.</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table></li>
```

Comment: This JSFiddle this great!  I've created a few example to illustrate my issue.  What I'm trying to achieve:

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/MrSpaceman/d6ya7LrL/ ...but I would like not to use the absolute repositioning {left: -40px} as this might break if I transplant the code (say).

Comment: P.S., the PDF thing is that I am creating a PDF with HTML, rather than putting a PDF within the HTML.