# CSS counter - numbered headings in different div

Tags: css

I'm trying to make numbered headings with CSS counters and it works pretty good when all headings are in same div, but when I need to reset counter to initial value in descendant div and continue with that counter from that new value in another div, then I have a problem.

> The scope of a counter starts at the first element in the document that has a 'counter-reset' for that counter and includes the element's descendants and its following siblings with their descendants.

Because of that I assume that when I reset-counter by some heading, new counter is set just for the div where that heading is and its descendants. So in next div no counter has been set and counting starts from beginning. Solution may be not to reset counter, but to set counter to initial value. But I haven't found way to do this. Is is possible? Or I have to use javascript for this way of using numbered headings? Or is there another solution?

```css
.text-container {
    counter-reset: section sub-section composite;
    h1.numbered {
        counter-reset: sub-section;
    }
    h2.numbered {
        counter-reset: composite;
    }
}

h1.numbered:before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: counter(section) " ";
}
h2.numbered:before {
    counter-increment: sub-section;
    content: counter(section) "." counter(sub-section) " ";
}
h3.numbered:before {
    counter-increment: composite;
    content: counter(section) "." counter(sub-section) "." counter(composite) " ";
}
```

```html
<div class="text-container">
  <div class="text-section">
    <div class="text-section-column">
      <h1 class="numbered">result 1 Heading</h1>
      <h2 class="numbered">result 1.1 Heading</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="text-section-column">
      <h3 class="numbered">result 1.1.1 Heading</h3>
      <h2 class="numbered">result 1.2 Heading</h2>
      <h3 class="numbered">result 1.2.1 Heading</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-section">
    <div class="text-section-column">
      <h3 class="numbered">result 1.2.1 Heading (expected 1.2.2)</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In third .text-section-column I want counting to continue from last value, but new counter is set.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start a new list, continuing the numbering from the previous list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615500/how-to-start-a-new-list-continuing-the-numbering-from-the-previous-list)

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I think it's not duplicate, because in question you suggested he has no need to reset any counter to initial value, and ol elements are in same div. And actually I think (and it look like it works that way) that when you reset counter inside descendant div, it is not accessible by parent nodes.

Comment: In my first comment I linked the official documentation, which, IMHO you should have (re)searched before asking. It has an example with sections and sub-sections numbering three levels deep. If that doesn't help, please clarify your question. In its current form it is unclear what you are asking. You can reset a CSS counter using `counter-reset: identifier;`

Comment: Of course I did read the documentation. So maybe I should express more precisely what is my problem. It's this feature of counters "Counters are "self-nesting", in the sense that resetting a counter in a descendant element or pseudo-element automatically creates a new instance of the counter."  So when I want to set value of counter to initial inside .text-section-column, counter-reset actually creates new instance of counter which is not accessible by next column in next text-section. Because that last column access the global counter, what I want to achieve is inside html code snippet.

Comment: So what I what I really want to do is decrement counter to zero. And not to use counter-reset which creates new instance.

Comment: @fuuchi do you allow to change your html structure, put only heading tags?

Comment: IMHO you can not expect such CSS features to work properly, if you “mess up” the HTML structure to begin with. How you have those different headlines nested into grouping divs seems to be rather arbitrary, and contradictory to the actual structure those headlines represent. I guess this was done due to design/layout restrictions/requirements? If you need to compromise the HTML due to that, then you might need to find a workaround for what CSS could achieve in a _proper_ structure as well.

Comment: @CBroe Unfortunately this html structure is result of business requirement of layout inside tinymce document. Only way to do it by css is by something like counter-increment: counter_id -(counter_value), but I think it's not possible, so I guess I will have to overcome this with javascript.

Answer (score 3):

#### Updated answer:

According to [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#scope):

> Counters are "self-nesting", in the sense that resetting a counter in a descendant element or pseudo-element automatically creates a new instance of the counter.

..., which means nesting will affect your arbitrary nested counters.

So you have two options:

#### A. Don't nest at all:

```css
.numbered:before { color: red; }

.text-container {
    counter-reset: a b 1 c;
}

h1.numbered {
  counter-increment: a;
  counter-reset: b;
}
h2.numbered {
  counter-increment: b;
  counter-reset: c;
}
h3.numbered {
  counter-increment: c;
}
h1.numbered:before {
  content: counter(a) " ";
}
h2.numbered:before {
    content: counter(a) "." counter(b) " ";
}
h3.numbered:before {
    content: counter(a) "." counter(b) "." counter(c) " ";
}
```

```html
<div class="text-container">
  <div class="text-section">
    <div class="text-section-column">
      <h1 class="numbered">result 1 Heading</h1>
      <h2 class="numbered">result 1.1 Heading</h2>
      <h3 class="numbered">result 1.1.1 Heading</h3>
      <h2 class="numbered">result 1.2 Heading</h2>
      <h3 class="numbered">result 1.2.1 Heading</h3>
      <h3 class="numbered">result <strike>1.2.1</strike> 1.2.2 Heading (expected 1.2.2)</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### B. Or, if you nest, do it properly:

```css
.numbered:before { color: red; }

.item {
 counter-increment: item; 
}
.item > .item {
  counter-reset: item;
}
.item ~ .item {
  counter-reset: none;
}
.item .numbered::before {
   content: counters(item, ".") " ";
}
```

```html
<div class="text-container">
  <div class="item">
    <h1 class="numbered">result 1 Heading</h1>
    <div class="item">
      <h2 class="numbered">result 1.1 Heading</h2>
      <div class="item">
        <h3 class="numbered">result 1.1.1 Heading</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h3 class="numbered">result 1.1.2 Heading</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h2 class="numbered">result 1.2 Heading</h2>
      <div class="item">
        <h3 class="numbered">result 1.2.1 Heading</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h3 class="numbered">result <strike>1.2.1</strike> 1.2.2 Heading (expected 1.2.2)</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

#### Initial answer:

<strike>I'm assuming you're looking for this?</strike>

```css
.numbered:before { color: red; }

.text-container {
    counter-reset: a b 1 c;
}

h1.numbered {
  counter-increment: a;
  counter-reset: b;
}
h2.numbered {
  counter-increment: b;
  counter-reset: c;
}
h3.numbered {
  counter-increment: c;
}
h1.numbered:before {
  content: counter(a) " ";
}
h2.numbered:before {
    content: counter(a) "." counter(b) " ";
}
h3.numbered:before {
    content: counter(a) "." counter(b) "." counter(c) " ";
}
```

```html
<div class="text-container">
  <div class="text-section">
    <div class="text-section-column">
      <h1 class="numbered">result 1 Heading</h1>
      <h2 class="numbered">result 1.1 Heading</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="text-section-column">
      <h3 class="numbered">result 1.1.1 Heading</h3>
      <h2 class="numbered">result 1.2 Heading</h2>
      <h3 class="numbered">result 1.2.1 Heading</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-section">
    <div class="text-section-column">
      <h3 class="numbered">result <strike>1.2.1</strike> 1.2.2 Heading (expected 1.2.2)</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but this doesn't work either. Try adding one more h3 heading before "1.2" heading, result of last h3 heading is then 1.2.3 but should be 1.2.2

Comment: @fuuchi, Updated answer with possible solutions.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to nest like this because of requirements of layout inside tinymce document. Only way to do it by css is by something like counter-increment: counter_id -(counter_value), but I think it's not possible, so I guess I will have to overcome this with javascript. Anyway thanks for help.