# Using CSS counter to number headings that are individually wrapped by div

Tags: css

I'm trying to make headings numbered using CSS counters on HTML code rendered from the CodeMirror markdown editor. I've already seen [tao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47770627/9096986) on a similar topic, but as you can see below, in my case, each heading is wrapped by an individual div which [makes it faulty](https://jsfiddle.net/cm3f8wtr/150/).

```css
.wrapper {
  counter-reset: a b c; /* ... */
}
h1.numbered {
  counter-increment: a;
  counter-reset: b;
}
h2.numbered {
  counter-increment: b;
  counter-reset: c;
}
/* ... */

h1.numbered::before {
  content: counter(a) " ";
}
h2.numbered::before {
  content: counter(a) "." counter(b) " ";
}
/* ... */
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div><h1 class="numbered">Heading 1</h1></div>
    <div><h2 class="numbered">Heading 1.1</h2></div>
    <div><h2 class="numbered">Heading 1.2</h2></div>
    <div><h1 class="numbered">Heading 2</h1></div>
    <div><h2 class="numbered">Heading 2.1</h2></div>
    <div><h2 class="numbered">Heading 2.2</h2></div>
</div>
```

I believe the reason is behind the initiation scope of counters (by counter-reset), possibly preventing them from holding the correct value or following the internal logic.

Please do let me know if you can think of any solution to this without the need to change the HTML structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to "initialise" (reset) both counters on their common ancestor. Values will be then bound to it and usable across all children. To really reset (in fact just set) sub-heading level, you have to use `counter-set` instead.

```css
body { counter-reset: h1 h2; }
h1 {
 counter-increment: h1;
 counter-set: h2 0;
}
h2 {
 counter-increment: h2;
}
h1::before { content: counter(h1) ' '; }
h2::before { content: counter(h1) '.' counter(h2) ' '; }
```

```html
<div><h1>Heading 1</h1></div>
<div><h2>Heading 1.1</h2></div>
<div><h2>Heading 1.2</h2></div>
<div><h1>Heading 2</h1></div>
<div><h2>Heading 2.1</h2></div>
<div><h2>Heading 2.2</h2></div>
```

`counter-reset` creates new "scope" in descendants and adjacent consecutive siblings. `counter-set` sets the value.

Comment: I see, from your updated question it really seems you just have to change `counter-reset` of sub-heading counters to `counter-set` and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks :] Amusing thing about this CSS mechanics is that despite it was in the specs for some time, actual `counter-set` support in browsers is quite recent.  In the past `counter-reset` did exactly what you had expected, despite specs. And current state when scope initialiser is called "reset" is also … funky.

Comment: Ah, that make sense, since the faulty solution was everywhere on the web which made me confused. How do you stay up to date about these details?

Comment: Well, frankly, I guess just like this :] You try or make something, it does not work or breaks, you are confused, then you search, ask or try to prepare a bug report and finally you the docs or someone answers and you learn something.  The bug report scenario was my case: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1729498. (Fun fact: that testcase in there works differently — i.e. the way my wrong assumptions were initially — in Google Chrome to this days, but I haven't found motivation to re-report it just yet.)